# MGF of sample mean of poisson distribution

Tags: poisson-distribution, convergence, moment-generating-function, iid, law-of-large-numbers

Let $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n\stackrel{iid}{\sim}Poiss(\lambda)$

Let mgf of $X_1$ is given by $M_X(t)=e^{\lambda(e^t-1)}$ and let $\bar{X_n}=\frac{1}{n}(X_1+X_2+\dots+X_n)$

Then, by Weak Law of Large Numbers $$\bar{X_n}\stackrel{P}{\rightarrow}\lambda=E[X_1]$$
Hence, $$e^{\bar{X_n}}\stackrel{P}{\to}e^{\lambda}$$
Hence, $$E[e^{\bar{X_n}}]\to e^{\lambda}----(1)$$
 and $Var(e^{\bar{X_n}})\to 0$

But, $$E[e^{\bar{X_n}}]=E[e^{\frac{1}{n}(X_1+X_2+\dots+X_n)}]=E[e^{\frac{1}{n}X_1}e^{\frac{1}{n}X_2}\dots e^{\frac{1}{n}X_n}]\stackrel{iid}{=}(E[e^{\frac{1}{n}X_1}])^n=(M_{X_1}(1/n))^n=(e^{\lambda(e^{\frac{1}{n}}-1)})^n=e^{n\lambda(e^{\frac{1}{n}}-1)}$$

Hence, $$E[e^{\bar{X_n}}]\nrightarrow e^{\lambda}----(2)$$

comparing $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get a contradiction, so
What am i doing wrong??

**Edit:**

In response to @whuber's comment:
as $n\to \infty, e^{\frac{1}{n}}\to 0$ hence, $(e^{\frac{1}{n}}-1)\to -1$, hence $e^{n\lambda(e^{\frac{1}{n}}-1)}\to e^{-\infty}=0$

Comment: Double-check your conclusion after the last "hence."

Comment: @whuber, as $n\to \infty, e^{\frac{1}{n}}\to 0$ hence, $(e^{\frac{1}{n}}-1)\to -1$, hence $e^{n\lambda(e^{\frac{1}{n}}-1)}\to e^{-\infty}=0$

Comment: You erred at the outset: $\exp(1/n) = 1 + 1/n + O(n^{-2})\to 1.$